# What is a counterexample that a composition of covering maps not a covering map?

Tags: algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, covering-spaces

Let $p:X\rightarrow Y$ and $q:Y\rightarrow Z$ be covering maps.

What would be an example that $q\circ p:X\rightarrow Z$ is not a covering map?

I saw a counterexample [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146976/composition-of-covering-maps/147164#147164), but it was too complex. Is there a relatively easy one?

Comment: How is anyone supposed to know ***what counterexample*** you found "too complex" if you don't tell us?

Comment: There are many different notions of covering map, used in different contexts.  For the ones I generally use, the composite of covering maps is a covering map.  What do you mean by covering map?

Comment: @ZevChonoles http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146976/composition-of-covering-maps/147164#147164

Comment: Moreover, I don't get what $X$ he means in the link.

Comment: @ColinMcLarty covering map $p:C\rightarrow X$ is a surjective continuous map such that for each $x\in X$, $x$ has an open neighborhood which is evenly covered by $p$.

Comment: Dear @Colin, I'm curious to know what **you** mean by covering map since I find quite strange that in your definition the composite of two covering maps is a covering map!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Etale covers, for example.  Open covers in analysis or differential geometry.  Covers in any Grothendieck topology.

Comment: see Hatcher's book section 1.3 ,problem no-6 on page no 79...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point is that if  $p:X\rightarrow Y$ and $q:Y\rightarrow Z$  are covering maps in this sense, but some $z\in Z$ has infinitely many $y_i\in Y$ with $q(y_i)=z$, then each $y_i$ may have some neighborhood $U_i\subseteq Y$ "evenly covered" by $p$ (I take this to mean the inverse image of $U_i$ is a union of parts each mapped isomorphically to $U_i$) but as $i$ varies the corresponding $U_i$ get smaller and smaller so that the intersection of all the images $q(U_i)$ is just $z$.  Then $z$ has no neighborhood $V\subseteq Z$ evenly covered by $qp$.

Bob Arthan's answer to  https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/147164/revisions includes reference to a proof that  if $p : X \rightarrow Y$ and $q :  Y \rightarrow Z$ are covering maps and if $Z$ is locally path-connected and semilocally simply-connected, then the composite $qp$ is a covering map.  So you will not get simpler counterexamples than the ones there.