A covering space map is a covering space
Let $\pi_1\colon Y_1 \rightarrow X$ and $\pi_2\colon Y_2 \rightarrow X$ be two covering spaces with the same base.  Let $f\colon Y_1 \rightarrow Y_2$ be a covering space map, i.e., a continuous map such that $\pi_1 = \pi_2 \circ f$.  Is it the case that $f$ has to itself be a covering space?  I think this follows from the classification of covering spaces if the $Y_i$ are path connected and $X$ is semilocally simply-connected, but it feels like the kind of thing that should be true in complete generality (edit: I'm far less sure about this now, see below).
Rob Arthan says that I should say something about what I've tried.  Basically I've done what he suggests: letting $y \in Y_2$ be a point, you can intersect open neighborhoods of $\pi_2(y)$ that are evenly covered by $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ to find an open neighborhood $U$ of $\pi_2(y)$ that is evenly covered by both $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$.  Letting $V$ be the sheet of $\pi_2$ lying above $U$ with $y \in V$, the obvious thing to do is to try to prove that $V$ is evenly covered by $f$.  For some reason I'm having trouble finishing the proof from there, but perhaps I'm missing something trivial?

I've thought more about this, and I'm less convinced that it should be true in total generality.  Let me explain by unpacking the second paragraph above some more.  The argument in that paragraph reduces us to the case of a trivial cover: replace $X$ by the open set $U$ over which both $\pi_1$ and $\pi_2$ are trivial, and replace $Y_1$ by $\pi_1^{-1}(U) \cong U \times I$ and $Y_2$ by $\pi_2^{-1}(U) \cong U \times J$ for discrete sets $I$ and $J$.
We then have a map
$$f\colon U \times I \longrightarrow U \times J$$
that commutes with the projections onto the $U$-factor, and the question is equivalent to whether $f$ must be a covering space.
The most optimistic thing would be to hope that there exists some map $g\colon I \rightarrow J$ such that $f(u,i)=(u,g(i))$ for all $u \in U$ and $i \in I$.  This would give the desired result.  If we could ensure that e.g. $U$ is path-connected, then this would definitely hold.  But in complete generality, I have no idea and would not be shocked to see counterexamples.

This may be relevant (but your question is not a duplicate): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1374247/what-is-a-counterexample-that-a-composition-of-covering-maps-not-a-covering-map

PS: I think you should say a bit more about what you have tried otherwise I think your very interesting question is likely to get down-voted and closed. If you have a go at the proof, I think you may find it's not actually too hard: try taking the intersection of a set $A$ that is evenly covered by $\pi_1$ and a set $B$ that is evenly covered by $\pi_2$ and seeing what you can say about $\pi_2^{-1}[A \cap B]$.

PPS: I think you mean $\pi_2 \circ f$, not $f \circ \pi_2$.

@RobArthan: Fixed the typo (thanks!), and added more about what I've tried.  I never know quite what to say: "I've tried the obvious things and can't quite make them work" seems silly, but if that's what people want I'll give it to them.

That is indeed what people want, silly or not: they want to know that you aren;t us using MSE as a question answering service. So thanks for the good question. I will have a think about it, but I am a bit rusty in this field and haven't much time for maths over the next few days. Maybe someone more on the ball than me will have an answer for you before then.

@RobArthan: Thanks!  I'm mostly active on MathOverflow (under a different name), so I'm only semi-aware of the norms here.  This question seemed more like a math.se question than a MO one, largely because I suspect I'm just missing something very easy.

@BasicQuestionBot Could you tell us what exactly "covering space" means to you? After all people often mean subtly different things by the term (and if your definition includes e.g. that the map be surjective then this is false for boring/trivial reasons).

@BenSteffan: I regard the map $\emptyset \rightarrow X$ as a covering space.  To me, a covering space is a map $\pi\colon Y \rightarrow X$ such that for all $x \in X$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is the disjoint union of subspaces ${\widetilde{U}i}{i \in I}$ such that the restriction of $\pi$ to each $\widetilde{U}_i$ is a homeomorphism onto $U$.  Implicit in this is that the topology on $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is the disjoint union topology on the union of the subspaces $\widetilde{U}_i$.

Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2152144/42781.

@BenSteffan I forgot the [.. debatable..] reason why technically and vacuously nonsurjective maps can still cover. To OP; this is very false if you insist covering maps surject. Maybe it’s not if you don’t.

@FShrike: Allowing nonsurjective maps to be covering spaces is a good convention since it is needed to make covering spaces closed under various operations.  It is also needed if you want covers of reasonable spaces to be the same as functors from the fundamental groupoid to sets (which is the best classification theorem since it allows disconnected bases and covers).  It doesn’t break the usual classification theorems involving the fundamental group since those are about spaces with basepoints, and once your cover has a basepoint it’s nonempty and thus you automatically get surjectivity.

On the general topic of "silliness", it helps the answerer to read how and where the questioner got stuck. There can be many different silly mistakes, and thus many answers to one silly mistake that are irrelevant to other silly mistakes, leading an OP to respond "Oh, yeah, I understant that, that's not what I meant", leading to an annoyed answerer.

On the topic of nonsurjectivity, allowing nonsurjective maps to be covering spaces completely breaks the theory of covering transformation groups.
