# Prove that composition of two covering maps is a covering map

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

> Suppose $X$ is locally simply connected. Show that, if $p: Y \to X$ and $q: Z \to Y$ are covering maps, then $p \circ q: Z \to X$ is also a covering map.

If $X, Y, Z$ were given to be connected, I could use properties of universal cover to solve the problem. I don't know how to proceed without that.

Comment: You may find https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146976/composition-of-covering-maps/147164#147164 useful, particularly the note http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2008/REUPapers/Jerzak.pdf mentioned there.

Comment: @RobArthan The first problem you linked is much easier. And the notes are standard stuff I already knew. I couldn't find anything new there. Can you maybe point me in a direction?

Comment: I wasn't saying your question was a duplicate. However the note by Jerzak referred to in the answers provides the answer to your question (and also shows that connectedness is not sufficient for the composite of two covering maps to be a covering map).

Comment: @RobArthan Sorry, I didn't mean to be rude. I think it's pretty useful. You should maybe make an answer out of it.

Comment: Did you try applying the definition of a covering map? Consider the preimages in $Y$ and $Z$ of an arbitrary point $x \in X$ and of neighborhoods of $x$.

Comment: No need to apologise: I didn't think you were being rude.