# Composition of fiber bundles is fiber?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, fiber-bundles

I was wondering, is the composition of fiber bundles a fiber bundle? (No smoothness imposed-just topological). I found this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/74611/is-the-composition-of-two-bundle-projections-necessarily-a-bundle-projection, I was wondering about a proof of item (b) in the case the maps are fiber bundles

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146976/composition-of-covering-maps may be of interest.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between your question and the question in the link. What is item (b) (in Georges Elencwajg's answer) for fiber bundles?

Comment: @ronno I am asking about fiber bundles. Item b is point b in Georges answer

Comment: But the counterexample in the covering spaces case is also a counterexample for fiber bundles. Are you asking if the composition of fiber bundles is a fiber bundle assuming the base has a universal cover?

Comment: @ronno yes. That's what i'm asking